# Normal lines of a regular surface

Tags: surfaces

I need to prove this:
If all the normal lines to a regular surface pass through a fixed point, then the surface is a portion of the sphere.
I haven't really tried much since I don't know what to do.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only true if the surfaced (let's call it $M$) is connected, I don't know whether your definition of 'regular' would imply this (otherwise the claim is true for each component).

Denote by $p_0$ the joint intersection point of the nomals to $M$. Consider a smooth curve $c(t)$ in $M$ and let $f(t) = ||c(t)- p_0||^2$ Then 
$$f^\prime(t) = 2 \langle c^{\prime}(t), c(t)-p_0\rangle = 0$$
since $c^\prime$ is tangent to $M$ and, by assumption, $c(t)-p_0$ normal to $M$. This shows that the distance from $M$ to $p_0$ is constant.